# Applying for a visa for a US trip sponsored by Google for a single, unemployed Indian citizen

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens

I'm a 28-year-old woman and currently unemployed as I'm studying on my own to become a Javascript developer. As a reward for finishing a course that was sponsored by Google, I received an invitation to attend the Google Developer Conference at their Mountain View, California office.

The company is sending a visa letter for me to produce in my application. The flight tickets, hotel accommodation and event ticket are also sponsored. The only things not covered are the visa fees, the transportation from airport to venue and food (there'll be lunch, breakfast and dinner at the conference).

I have never visited the US and I have no connections there. This trip will last 5 days and I'll be back to India. I've heard numerous unemployed people facing rejection in their visa interview. How must I deal with this situation?

Comment: An Invitation from Google? That is pretty da** exciting!. If you don't make any obvious blunder in your application I see a lot of chances of success. Having no connections in the US is a good thing to demonstrate non immigrant intent. Focus on trying to prove that you do need to come back to your country after this event.

Comment: Can you clarify what your actual question is?

Comment: @JonathanReez My question is that I've been granted an invitation letter for B1 visa by Google but currently I'm studying on my own to become a developer. So what are the chances of getting a visa under these circumstances. I've never visited U.S. nor do I have connections there. If I visit, It'll be just because of this opportunity.

Comment: To be successful in your visa application, you need to show evidence of the reasons why you must return to India. This may be difficult if you are not employed.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, nobody can predict your chances here, and you can only find out when you apply. However from your description it looks like you do have a credible cause for this visit which will be a positive factor in the decision.

> How must I deal with this situation?

You have to build a case that you have **very strong reasons to return to your country after this visit**. Secondly, you need to demonstrate that you can comfortably afford to pay the expenses which are not covered by your sponsor.

Many first time applicants, including me, make a mistake of focusing too hard on the *credible reason to visit* part and fail to build up a strong case of their need to come back. Focus on that part in your application and your interview. Present all your ties to your home country, for example a letter from your University about your studies to name one.